# Why we do not use r squared for logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, r-squared, pseudo-r-squared

Why we do not use R squared for logistic regression? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: A more general concept is [deviance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)). 

In the case of Gaussian distributed errors the deviance is equal to sum of squared error. That sun of squared error and the related R-squared is a special case.

Comment: can you be more spesific? Basicly how can we prove that r squared is not valid for logistic regression?

Comment: There is no logic behind it in the sense of a rigorous proof. That is because R^2 neither has proof when it is used for an ordinary linear model. R^2 is just a Pearson correlation between observed values and modeled/fitted values. Correlations with variables that have only values 0 and 1 can be done as well. It doesn't need proof. It is just that correlations with normal distributed variables have a more intuitive explanation.